# What is the closure of the span of separable functions in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ denote the space of all finite sums of **multiplicative** **separable** functions of two variables, i.e., $X$ consists of functions $f(x_1,x_2)$ of the form:
$$
f(x_1, x_2) = \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x_1)h_k(x_2).
$$
My question is what is the closure of $X$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

The above fixes the coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$. If we denote $Y$ as the space of all finite sums of functions each of which is multiplicative separable **with respect to some coordinates** $(y_1, y_2)$. Then what is the closure of $Y$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

How about other natural spaces? Is $X$ or $Y$ dense in certain natural spaces?

Comment: I'd start by specializing to $\chi_{A\times B}(x_1,x_2) = \chi_{A}(x_1)\chi_{B}(x_2)$.  What is in the closure of the span of such functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: Thank you! sounds a good idea. My understanding is that first use characteristic functions of rectangles to approach the characteristic function of an arbitrary bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then approach the characteristic function of an arbitrary bounded measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then we get simple functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, lastly we get density in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for every $1 \leq p < \infty$. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is $L^{2}(\mathbb R^{2})$ because its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$. If $\iint f(x,y) g(x)h(y)d(x,y)=0$ for all $g , h \in L^{2}(\mathbb  R)$ then  $\int f(x,y)g(x)dx=0$ for almost all $y$. Hence, $f(x,y)=0$ for almost all $x$, for almost all $y$. By Fubini's Theorem this implies that $f=0$ a.e..

This argument works for in $L^{2}(\mu)$.

It may also be noted that if $(e_n)$ and $(f_m)$ are orthonormal bases for $L^{2}(\mathbb  R)$ then $(e_n(x)f_m(y))_{n, m \geq 1})$ is an orhtonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb  R^{2})$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real sledgehammer approach, the closure is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn’t think of that. Thank you! My understanding is that, firstly approach $L^2$ function by a compactly supported continuous function, and then approach this function on the compact set by polynomial using stone-Weierstrass. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is generally correct. The basic point is that sup norm is "stronger' than $L^2$ norm. However, I would not say that this argument is any better than Kavi's argument (it uses a lot more machinery).

Comment: Got it, thank you!